# Loop through Multidimensional array and update mysql table using codeignitor 3

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop through multidimensional array to update the values in mysql table in codeignitor 3

I have an issue in looping through the values in multidimensional array

Below is my Multidimensional array:

```php
$data = array(
    'invoice_id' => $invoice_id,
    'date' => $this->input->post('date',true),
    'commercial_invoice_number' => $this->input->post('commercial_invoice_number',true),
    'payment_type' => $this->input->post('payment_type',true)
);
```

When printing this array ,$data contains as below

```
(
    [invoice_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4549344712
            [1] => 4549344713
            [2] => 4549344814
        )
    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25-11-2022
            [1] => 22-12-2022
            [2] => 12-10-2022
        )
    [commercial_invoice_number] => Array
        (
            [0] => NS202211-4
            [1] => NS202211-5
            [2] => NS202211-6
        )
    [payment_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )
        )
```

print_r($invoice_id) returns as below

`Array ( [0] => 4549344712 [1] => 4549344713 [2] => 4549344814 )`

```php
foreach ($invoice_id as $value) {
    $this->db->where('invoice_id', $value);
    $this->db->update('invoice', $data);

    echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

The above code giving me Array to String conversion error.

Comment: could you please update your question with a result of `print_r($invoice_id)` and please update your question with text and not images of code/data/errors

Comment: @Vickel Updated. Image is also removed